# Joomla URL parameters

Tags: url-routing, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I would like to get your opinions and solutions on how can I solve this problem.

I have a website that displays restaurants, events and attractions in multiple cities and countries. 
Right now I implemented the following structure:

```
Country A
--City A-1
----Restaurants
----Events
----Attractions
--City A-2
----Restaurants
----Events
----Attractions
Country B
--City B-1
----Restaurants
----Events
----Attractions
--City B-2
----Restaurants
----Events
----Attractions
```

There is so much redundancy, specially when it comes to modules that display content from specific categories.
What I thought would be a good solution, is to only create categories for Restaurants, Events and attractions, and figure out a way to specify which country and city by adding parameters to the URLS.

I would appreciate any thoughts and suggestions.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid creating the full menu in the menu manager.

As for modules you could add a textfield inside the module with an array like: 1,7:2,8... = menu_id_1,content_of_city_7:menu_id_2,content_of_city_8...

You will have just one module for each type (restaurant, event, attraction) connected to all menus you want to be displayed and you will check the content of it matching the menu id from url with your array.